# Segmentation Fault *After* Input Ends When fgets() Reads Too Many Characters

Tags: c, fgets

I'm a lab assistant at my university for computer science labs, and during a first week course a student showed following code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

static void copy (FILE *, FILE *);

int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
    copy (stdin, stdout);
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}

static void copy (FILE *input, FILE *output)
{
    char c[2];
    while(fgets(c, 5, input) != NULL) {
        fputs(c, output);
    }
}
```

*The code in the above example works as if there's no problem with reading five characters into a char array of size 2, but then results in a segmentation fault once EOF has been reached in stdin.*

We were learning about using also sorts of input and output functions and they found this code had bizarre functionality.

You would expect (or so I'd think) some sort of error when fgets attempted to read more characters into the variable 'c' than it had space.

However, this code performs entirely as one would suspect of a fully functioning program of the same ilk (echoing characters typed into standard input), then segfaults *after* the EOF character is typed. This segmentation fault can be prevented by only typing n-2 or less characters in between each newline, but otherwise always triggers after the EOF character is typed (regardless of how many lines were previously typed).

Why does this happen? It seems almost like my program is waiting until the end of the program to tell me it had a segmentation fault twenty lines of input ago!

Comment: That's not C code. Please post actual code, not pseudocode. It sounds like you have undefined behavior  (writing more characters than the array can hold). Undefined behavior doesn't guarantee you a crash or any kind of consistent error, it can do *anything*, even appearing to work properly. Oftentimes it works fine until you present the code to a customer or release it to production. What's likely happening is that it's just writing the chars anyway and causes your stack frame to get corrupted.

Comment: Perhaps messing up a return address on the stack. So the segfault occurs when the function ends, not during it. This is the kind of reason why a fault can seem to have nothing to do with where the damage was done. Writing to an invalid array element can affect a function several steps away on the call stack.

Comment: @Blaze Sorry, of course. I've included the exact code used in the lab. Does 'undefined behaviour' essentially mean this just does what it does because it does? I'd prefer to have a better explanation for both myself and the student, but if this is an error totally outside of the intended scope of the function, I guess that's the best I'll get.

Comment: [This question may help](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2397984). The bottom line is that C has rules that the programmer ***must*** follow. It's up to the programmer to understand all of the rules, and follow the rules. The C language (unlike other languages) makes no attempt to enforce the rules. If you break the rules (e.g. by writing past the end of an array), then anything could happen.

Comment: If your job involves teaching C, you absolutely **must** know what "undefuned behaviour" means.

Comment: @n.m. Fair enough. While my job is only assisting students in debugging basic programs and marking lab work (teaching is left with to people with far more experience than me, I'm just a second year computer science student), this is definitely stuff I should no more on (which is partially the reason I'm trying to learn more on forums such as this). Thanks for making it clear how important this is though, I'll make sure to do some reading.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a simple classic case of buffer overflow because of sloppy programming.
Buffer overflow results in undefined behaviour.

```
...
char c[2];                            // your declare your array with 2 elements
while(fgets(c, 5, input) != NULL) {   // but here you pretend it has 5 elements
    fputs(c, output);
...
```

You want this:

```
...
char c[2];   // btw 2 is execcsively small anyway
while(fgets(c, sizeof c, input) != NULL) {   // use correct size of c here
    fputs(c, output);
...
```

Undefined behaviour means exactly that: the bevaiour is undefined, anything can happen including:

- apparently working fine
- segmentation fault
- wrong data output
- data corruption
- program stuck
- other erratic behaviour

Comment: While this certainly answers my question, I'd like to point out that it was intentional that this program failed (in contrast to 'sloppy programming', the students were trying to make the program fail as a learning exercise). We expected (as stated in the question), that there would be an error, but when the students asked "Why does this exact thing happen?", I didn't have an answer. All I could get was the specific the conditions under which the bug occurred. Explaining undefined behaviour and why it applies here should do the trick though, thanks for the thorough explanation!